# Fiddler is not capturing libgit2 traces

Tags: fiddler, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am using libgit2 to push my repository to server. But Fiddler not capturing HTTP/HTTPS traces during push operation.

Which protocol(git, http or winhttp) libgit2 uses to push reporsitory when we provide basic auth credentials ?

Why Fiddler not capturing libgit2 traces ?

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler sets up your browser's default proxy, but does not necessarily set the proxy for other applications.  libgit2 uses WinHTTP (on Windows) and thus uses its proxy settings which do "[not inherit browser proxy settings.  WinHTTP does not share any proxy settings with Internet Explorer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384098(v=vs.85).aspx)"

You will need to either set the WinHTTP proxy when using fiddler, via `netsh`, or simply set the `core.httpproxy` and `core.httpsproxy` settings in your repository.